# SQLite where condition - compare two last rows

Tags: query, sqlite, python

I have a SQLite DB table like this:

```
[Stock_price_Table]:

+-----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|code |    date     | first  |    open    | close  |    sma_9     | sma_26     | rsi     |
+-----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|1223 | 20200213    | 205    | 205        | 300    | 225          | 300        | 20      | 
|1223 | 20200313    | 209    | 209        | 340    | 235          | 330        | 70      | 
|4556 | 20200213    | 205    | 205        | 300    | 225          | 300        | 67      | 
|4443 | 20200213    | 205    | 205        | 300    | 225          | 300        | 33      | 
|9877 | 20200218    | 205    | 205        | 300    | 225          | 300        | 39      |    +-----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+

I want to compare last two records of each stock and get the stocks that have these conditions:

1. `sma_9[n] >= sma_26[n] && sma_9[n-1] <= sma_26[n-1]`

2. `rsi[n] >= rsi[n-1]`

where [n] is last record and [n-1] the next-to-last.

I can do this in python and dataframe like below, but I want to do it using SQL code:

    stocks = db.session.query(Stocks).all()

    for stock in enumerate(stocks):
       query = f"select * from Stock_price_Table where code = {stock.code}"

       df = pd.read_sql(query, db.engine)

       result1=((df.iloc[-1]['SMA_9'] >= df.iloc[-1]['SMA_26']) & (df.iloc[-2]['SMA_9'] <= df.iloc[-2]['SMA_26']))

       result2=(df.iloc[-1]['rsi'] >= df.iloc[-2]['rsi'])
```

Comment: [SQLite - Window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#biwinfunc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (it's hard to verify without a fiddle):

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT code, sma_9, sma_26, rsi,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date DESC) AS rank
  FROM Stock_price_Table
)
SELECT t1.code
  FROM temp AS t1
  INNER JOIN temp AS t2
    ON t1.code = t2.code
   AND t1.rank = 1
   AND t2.rank = 2
  WHERE t1.sma_9 >= t1.sma_26
    AND t2.sma_9 <= t2.sma_26
    AND t1.rsi >= t2.rsi
```

Basically, in the `temp` table you select the stock records, `RANK`ed by date and 'grouped' by `code` (through the `PARTITION BY` clause). In the main `SELECT`, you link the first and second ranked records per stock code, and select only those which match your criteria (the `WHERE` clause).